# npm error .... nodejs while installing express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I've faced this problem and i don't know how to solve it and go beyond , please I need your help

PS C:\Users\Karrar\Desktop\Html&Css project\heelow_files> npm install express -save
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rl":"~1.0.1","escape-'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Karrar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-02T21_50_04_441Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Karrar\Desktop\Html&Css project\heelow_files>

Comment: Please post the contents of your log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

`$ npm cache clean --force` and try again.

This issue happens most commonly due to [caching](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468).